# Data not transferring from one fragment to another using ViewModel and LiveData

Tags: android, mvvm, android-livedata, mutablelivedata

I have 2 fragments:

`HomeFragment`
`ListFragment`

I am trying to send data from `HomeFragment` to `ListFragment` using ViewModel and LiveData but i am not able to do so. `ListFragment` is not updating the value.

So i have 2 buttons:
**Groceries** and **Electronics** in `HomeFragment`
Whichever button i click on `HomeFragment` should be updated to `ListFragment`

### MainActivityViewModel.kt

```
class MainActivityViewModel : ViewModel() {

    private val itemType = MutableLiveData<String>()
    val itemTypeData : LiveData<String>
    get() = itemType

    init {
        itemType.value = "No Item"
    }

    fun updateItemType(type: Int){
        if(type == 0) itemType.value = "Groceries"
        else itemType.value = "Electronics"
    }

}
```

### HomeFragment.kt

```
class HomeFragment : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var mainViewModel : MainActivityViewModel

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        val binding : FragmentHomeBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.fragment_home, container, false)

        mainViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(MainActivityViewModel::class.java)
        binding.viewModel = mainViewModel
        binding.lifecycleOwner = this

        binding.tvGroceries.setOnClickListener {
            mainViewModel.updateItemType(0)
            it.findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_homeFragment_to_listFragment)
        }
        binding.tvElectronics.setOnClickListener {
            Log.d("sagar", "clicked ")
            mainViewModel.updateItemType(1)
            it.findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_homeFragment_to_listFragment)
        }

        return binding.root
    }

}
```

### ListFragment.kt

```
class ListFragment : Fragment() {
    private lateinit var mainViewModel : MainActivityViewModel

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        val binding : FragmentListBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.fragment_list, container, false)

        mainViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(MainActivityViewModel::class.java)
        binding.viewModel = mainViewModel
        binding.lifecycleOwner = this
        return binding.root
    }

}
```

### fragment_list.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout>
    <data>
        <variable
            name="viewModel"
            type="com.example.ecompractice.MainActivityViewModel" />
    </data>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/frameLayout2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ListFragment">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="55dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="54dp"
        android:text="@{viewModel.itemTypeData}"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

ListFragment Always Print: **No Item**

I have tried watching tutorials and reading some articles but none helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after 2 hours, i figured out what the problem was.

Problem was being caused by this line:

`mainViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(MainActivityViewModel::class.java)`

Here, i am making each of these fragments owner of themselves. But instead, we are supposed to make the `activity` the owner of all these fragments so that data can be transferred between these fragments.